# How to import a lib from one cabal package to another

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, cabal-new

So my folder structure is like this

```
.
├── eulerlibs
│  ├── EulerLibs
│  └── eulerlibs.cabal
├── flake.lock
├── flake.nix
├── p001
│  ├── Main.hs
│  └── p001.cabal
├── p002
│  ├── Main.hs
│  └── p002.cabal
├── p003
│  ├── Main.hs
│  └── p003.cabal
├── p004
│  ├── Main.hs
│  └── p004.cabal
├── p005
│  ├── Main.hs
│  └── p005.cabal
```

What I am trying to do is import the library modules in the `./eulerlibs` (library) cabal directory to lets say `./p005`(executable) cabal directory
I do understand that I can include built libraries (*.so), but can find no way of linking two cabal projects 
I'm very new to cabal as well as haskell so some insight will be much appreciated. If nothing works out I'll have to add the library to p005 itself which I really want to avoid.

Comment: By the way, linking *.so files manually is very uncommon in Haskell. That is definitely not something you should do as a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a `cabal.project` file. Place it at the top level (in the `.` directory) with these contents:

```
packages: */*.cabal
```

Then you will be able to use all those libraries in each other's cabal files in the build-dependencies, e.g. in `p001.cabal`:

```
...

library
  ...
  build-depends: base, eulerlibs
  ...

...
```

Here is the full documentation of `cabal.project` files: https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for, a file to manage workspace members.